# Stop jOOQ stripping characters from SQL field

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I am implementing a function to get an estimate of the count as described in the PostgreSQL documentation here https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Count_estimate

I'm using the function:

```
public static Field<Integer> countEstimate(final QueryPart query) {
    final String sql = String.format("count_estimate(%s)", escape(query.toString()));
    return field(sql(sql), PostgresDataType.INT);
}
```

Which looks fine until I pass it an <s>IN clause</s> array field in the query. When this happens jOOQ strips the array curly braces from within my SQL. e.g. Calling it with this java code:

```
final UUID[] ids = new UUID[]{UUID.randomUUID()};
return db.select(countEstimate(db.select(TABLE.ID)
    .from(TABLE)
    .where(overlaps(ids, TABLE.FILTER_IDS))));
```

Results in both the variable `sql` and `DSL.sql(sql)` in the above function rendering:

```
count_estimate(E'select "schema"."table"."id"
from "schema"."table"
where (
  ((\'{"75910f3b-83e6-41ed-bf57-085c225e0131"}\') && ("schema"."table"."filter_ids"))
)')
```

But `field(sql(sql), PostgresDataType.INT)` renders this:

```
count_estimate(E'select "schema"."table"."id"
from "schema"."table"
where (
  ((\'"75910f3b-83e6-41ed-bf57-085c225e0131"\') && ("schema"."table"."filter_ids"))
)')
```

Is there any way to work around this and to tell jOOQ to leave my query alone?

(jOOQ 3.8.3, PG 9.5.5, PG driver 9.4-1203-jdbc4)

Comment: How did you implement `escape()`? It looks like you're using a PostgreSQL-specific, non-standard escape sequence starting with `E'...'`. Why?

Comment: ... note the `{}` may be stripped because they have a meaning in JDBC (escape sequences) and in jOOQ (templating). They shouldn't have a meaning inside of a string literal, but if you prepend `E'...'` to your string literal, jOOQ currently may not recognise its format.

Comment: Hi Lukas, thank you for the explanation of why `{}` gets stripped.

In this case `escape` is implemented as:

    `private static String escape(final String val) {
        return "E'" + val.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace("'", "\\'") + "'";
    }`

I'm using the `E'...'` version of quoting rather than `$$` because the transformation above should always map back to the original query after PG interprets the string, no matter the contents of the query, whereas I can't see how to safely escape `$$` (or `$foo$`, etc) from inside a query in a manner than will still execute correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it only strips `'{}'` style arrays. Replacing the code that turns the `UUID[]` into sql from

```
DSL.val(ids)
```

with

```
DSL.array(Arrays.stream(ids)
    .map(UUID::toString)
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .toArray(new String[0]))
    .cast(PostgresDataType.UUID.getArrayDataType()
```

results in it rendering `cast(array[\'75910f3b-83e6-41ed-bf57-085c225e0131\'] as uuid[])` prevents it being stripped